# Finding all rows in a pair of vectors where both entries are non-zero (Octave)

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a n x 2 matrix in Octave, and I would like to find every row where the matrix(row, 1) and matrix(row, 2) elements are non-zero. I could use a for loop like this:

```
[nrows, ncols] = size(data);
for i = 1:nrows
    if(data(i, 1) ~= 0 && data(i, 2) ~= 0)
        % Do something
    end
end
```

The issue with that is that n is about 3 million, and iteration in Octave takes for ever. I feel like there is a way to do it with find, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Anyone have any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create use logical indexing:

```
idx = all(data(:,1:2)~=0, 2);
```

The resulting vector `idx` contains `1`s in every row where both cells are non-zero and `0` otherwise.

Comment: and then use `find(idx)` to get the indexes of these elements.

Comment: @FabianTamp: That depends completely on the things OP wants to do with his data. There are many operations where the indices are not necessary and since `find` is computationally expensive (compared to omitting it) I would always try to avoid it and stick with the logical indices.

Comment: Fair call. I figured @anjruu's mention of `find` in the question probably warranted a mention to it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case (since it is related with zero values) the following also should work

`idx=(data(:,1).*data(:,2)~=0)`

But @H.Muster's solution is the one that works in all cases, hence a better one.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is the issue: maybe try converting both columns to logical:

```
useful = and(logical(data(:,1)),logical(data(:,2)))
```

Then you can again use logical indexing:

```
filtered = data(useful,:)
```